# How to wait async operation in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-splashscreen

**MyViewModel.kt**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SplashScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tokenManager: TokenManager
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(SplashScreenState())
    val state: StateFlow<SplashScreenState> = _state.asStateFlow()

   

    fun refreshAccessToken(refreshToken: String) {

        runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO){
            val job = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

                try {
                    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                    loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient
                        .Builder()
                        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                        //.authenticator(AuthAuthenticator(tokenManager))
                        .build()

                    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .build()

                    val service = retrofit.create(RegisterService::class.java)

                    val response = service.refreshToken(model = RefreshToken(refreshToken))

                    if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                        val newAccessToken = response.body()?.access_token
                        val newRefreshToken = response.body()?.refresh_token
                        if (newAccessToken != null && newRefreshToken != null) {
                            tokenManager.saveAccessToken(newAccessToken)
                            tokenManager.saveRefreshToken(newRefreshToken)
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            error = true
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            job.join()
        }
    }

    
}

data class SplashScreenState(
  
    val error: Boolean = false,
)
```

**SplashActivity.kt**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
@SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")
class SplashActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val viewModel: SplashScreenViewModel by viewModels()
    private val tokenManager = TokenManager(this)
    val activity = this
    val errMsg = "Bir hata ile karşılaşıldı."

    private var isTokenExist = false


    fun navigateToMain(isTokenExist: Boolean) {
        val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("isTokenExist", isTokenExist)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }


    private suspend fun getRefreshToken() {
        tokenManager.getRefreshToken().collect { refreshToken ->
            if (refreshToken != null) {
                 viewModel.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken) // I need the wait this operation result and go to navigateToMain
                navigateToMain(true)
              
            } else {
               navigateToMain(false)
              
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
            splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (viewModel.state.value.error) {
            Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity, errMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            getRefreshToken()
        }      
    }
}
```

I have to wait for the refreshAccessToken to finish, then I have to navigateToMain if the process is finished, but I guess I am stuck in splash activity because SplashActivity is the first opened activity and runblocking blocks this thread. Actually, I couldn't understand what the problem was exactly, but I think this seems to be the problem. Can you help me ? I want to wait until the refreshAccessToken operation finishes and navigateToMain.

Also, I do not know the best practice on this subject, how good is it, can anyone tell me?

Comment: you are not updating your state in the viewmodel also not collecting it in the Activity.

Comment: `refreshAccessToken` needs to be a suspend function with no `runBlocking`, `launch`, or `job.join()` in it. Then it will be synchronous and non-blocking, so you can call it from your Activity or Fragment's coroutine or suspend functions.

Comment: Thank you for answer @Tenfour04 I understand however I don't need to wait for the refreshAccessToken function to finish, right? because it is already doing its job in the background and refresh the token. I am already sending true  if token exist ,if not I am sending false and navigate according to this case. if I remove runblocking ,suspend and withcontext and I just add for example viewmodelscope.launch , it will work right clearly?

Comment: That’s right if you don’t need to wait for it. Your question title says you want to wait. I don’t understand what you’re doing in your collector. If you aren’t waiting for the new refresh token and you make this function asynchronous, then you will be navigating before the token is available. Maybe that is your intent.

Comment: I wrote the title that way because I thought I had to wait but I understand thanks again @Tenfour04.